# Entrar minúsculo/maiúsculo em C

Tags: c

Como faço para que independente do usuário digitar a letra em minúscula ou maiúscula ser lida pelo scanf_s?

```
printf("\nVocê gostou do nosso produto?\n" 
            "\n[S] - Sim"
            "\n[N] - Não\n\n"
            "RESPOSTA:\t\n");
scanf_s(" %c", &p);
```

Comment: Você quer que toda a entrada seja formatada pra minuscula ou maiúscula ?

Comment: Toda "letra" é lida pelo scanf, seja maiúscula ou minúscula. Se está tendo problema, definitivamente não é no código que postou. Seria importante [edit] e fornecer um [mcve] do problema. Muito provavelmente sua pergunta é um [Problema XY](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/499/70).

Answer (score 0):

Utilize a função `toupper` de `<ctype.h>`.
Após seu scanf faça:

```
p = toupper(p);
```

que p transformará em maiúscula independente de ter sido digitada em maiúscula ou minúscula.